# In bash alias command, how to make a result of PHP script available to the rest of the bash script?

Tags: php, bash, alias

So, the PHP script returns (or maybe needs to echo the value?) a value, e.g. 32, I want the rest of the alias to rename file `test.txt` to `test32.txt`, so to append THAT value (32) to `test` and append then the value `.txt`, so to rename it. What is the command to take this value from PHP and use it in command `mv test.txt test32.txt` ?

Tha PHP script that I run is:

```
php getValue.php
```

This command returns a number value (e.g. 32).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have PHP print the value to stdout:

```php
<?php
echo 32;
```

Then use [command substitution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4651437/how-do-i-set-a-variable-to-the-output-of-a-command-in-bash) to capture the output as a string:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

mv test.txt "test$(php getValue.php).txt"
```

Answer (score 0):

getValue.php:

```
<?php
echo rand(0,100);
?>
```

script.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash
phpvalue=`php getValue.php`

file=$1
extension="${file##*.}"
filename="${file%.*}"
mv "$file" "${filename}${phpvalue}.${extension}"
```

Example usage: ./script.sh test.txt